# Model(#...) expected, got String(#...) error when using select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, has-one

I scaffolded a simple example to illustrate a problem I'm having.
In this example I have a Starship and a Pilot. I want to be able to assign an existing pilot to the starship at creation.

**starship.rb**

```
class Starship < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :pilot

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

**pilot.rb**

```
class Pilot < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :starship, optional: true

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

**starships/_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :pilot %>
  <%= f.select :pilot, Pilot.all %>
</div>
```

**starships_controller.rb**

```
  def starship_params
    params.require(:starship).permit(:name, :pilot)
  end
```

**params hash**

```
{"name"=>"Nostromo", "pilot"=>"#<Pilot:0x007f85ff547f90>"}
```

And I get this error

```
Pilot(#70106745549840) expected, got String(#70106709663840)
```

I see that my pilot is sent as a string in the hash, but I don't seem to find how I am supposed to do it otherwise.

Comment: You cant pass a object to the params hash like that. You could try sending the `id` of that object and later find that the object in your destination.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use collection select and return just the pilot id.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:pilot_id, Pilot.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Note that you'll need to change your starship_params

```
  def starship_params
    params.require(:starship).permit(:name, :pilot_id)
  end
```

Add an attr_accessor for :pilot_id

```
class Starship < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :pilot_id
```

Modify your create as follows...

```
def create
  @starship = Starship.new(starship_params)
  @starship.pilot = Pilot.find(@starship.pilot_id)
  respond_to do |format|
    ...
```

Comment: I tried this but I get this error now `undefined method `pilot_id' for #<Starship id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> Did you mean? pilot`. Any Idea of where I may have made a mistake ?

Comment: Ah, right, sorry, it's a `has_one`.  Answer modified.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You have a one to one optional relationship. Just listing all pilots can overwrite them. Its better to create a new pilot than assigning one from whole list.

Still if you want to use try this code. Remember you can also use `Pilot.pluck(:id)` below if you want to transfer pilot.

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :pilot_id %>
  <%= f.select :pilot_id, Pilot.where('starship_id is NULL').pluck(:id) %>
</div>
```

Now in your `starship_controller`  create method
write

```
def create
    @starship = Starship.new(starship_params)
    pilot = @starship.build_pilot
    pilot.id= params[:starship][:pilot_id]
    pilot.reload
    respond_to do |format|
      if @starship.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Starship successfully created.' }
       else
         format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Error occured.' }
       end
end
```

Your strong params should be

```
def starship_params
    params.require(:starship).permit(:name, :pilot_id)
end
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I got `Couldn't find Pilot without an ID`. I tried with `f.select :pilot` and `params.require(:starship).permit(:name, :pilot)` instead and got the original error again

Answer (score 0):

> Just replace below code with your code and you are good to go.

```
<%= f.label :pilot %>
<%= f.select :pilot, Pilot.all.map{ |p| [p.name, p.id] } %>
```

This will show pilot's name in the select dropdown and will save particular pilot's id while saving.

Comment: Still got the same error here but with this hash now `{"name"=>"Nostromo", "pilot"=>"2"}`